# Inverse of a trace based function?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse-function

I have the following linear operator:
[image]
and I need to compute its inverse operator [image] for y: vector of real values.
[image]

The trace function is invertible as far as I know, so is this even possible? and if so, how can I compute the inverse operator in this case?

Comment: What do we know about the $a_m$?

Comment: a_{m} is a vector of Nx1 that I have computed. More can be found here: [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=8328805)

Comment: And how are we meant to interpret $tr\{a_ma_m^HC\}$?  Is the output an array of values?  If so, how many values are in the array?

Comment: By the way, you can format things mathematically by putting things between `$`'s.  For instance, typing `$\Theta:\Bbb C \in C^{N \times N}$` results in $\Theta:\Bbb C \in C^{N \times N}$